# Format Powershell SQL query to print all items in columns

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I am using this style of sql connection and want to output the data into a table format but am only getting back the number of items. Having issues installing invoke-sql on old server not sure what the deal is... If any suggestions that would be great, for users that are stuck invoking sql like this :)

```
$user = "user"
$pwd = "password"
$SQLDBNAME = "database"
$SQLServer = ".\SQLEXPRESS"
$TagTable = "TagTable"
$sqlQuery = "SELECT TOP (10) [TagName] FROM [FactoryTalk_Datalog].[dbo].[TagTable]"
$sqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection

$sqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=$SQLServer;Database=$SQLDBName;uid=$user;pwd=$pwd"


#Create and configure a command object
$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$SqlCmd.CommandText = $SqlQuery
$SqlCmd.Connection = $sqlConnection

#Create and configure a DataAdpater/DataSet pair of objects
$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet

#Fill Dataset with Data and close the connection to the database
$SqlAdapter.Fill($Dataset)
Write-Host $DataSet
#$DataSet | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Users\admin\Documents\sqlApplication" -NoTypeInformation -Force
$sqlConnection.Close()
```

Comment: I've never had issue with older SQL Servers.  Try login with SQL Server Management Studio and try query inside SSMS.  I always test my queries inside SSMS before using in a code. Any query that works inside SSMS will work in Powershell.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me :) using .Tables wrote it out perfect.

```
#Fill Dataset with Data and close the connection to the database
$SqlAdapter.Fill($Dataset)
$DataSet.Tables | Format-Table
write-host $DataSet
#$DataSet | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Users\admin\Documents\sqlApplication" -NoTypeInformation -Force
$sqlConnection.Close()
```

Comment: It's hard to see what's going on because of the poor formatting and the commented-out CSV export that's irrelevant to your question, but you don't need the `write-host` - `$DataSet.Tables | Format-Table` should be sufficient.